Get File from path in Drupal with PHP
I am working on a custom module with Drupal. The user uploads a .zip file (this zip file contains many .docx files), the .zip gets extracted, and Nodes are created.
For each .docx file, a Node is created with the content of the file, and the actual file as an attachment.
I can successfully upload the .zip, extract the .zip, read every .docx, create Nodes with the contents of the .docx, but the only thing that I cannot figure out, is how to add the .docx as an attachment.

THERE'S QUITE A BIT OF CODE HERE, YOU DON'T NEED TO LOOK IN DEPTH IN ALL THE CODE, I HAVE ADDED COMMENTS IN EVERY "CHUNK" OF CODE FOR WHAT IT DOES, AND THE PARTS THAT ARE IMPORTANT I HAVE BRIEFLY EXPLAINED.

A small guide through my code:
In this function I basically create a form so that the user can upload the zip file. No problems here.
 public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['zip_file'] = [
      '#type' => 'managed_file',
      '#title' => $this->t('Upload Zip File'),
      '#description' => $this->t('Upload a zip file containing Word documents.'),
      '#upload_validators' => [
        'file_validate_extensions' => ['zip'],
      ],
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#upload_location' => 'temporary://word_document_import', // Custom upload location

    ];
  
    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];
    return $form;
  }

Here in the next function, I basically take the .zip, I extract it, and I use the extracted files to pass as parameters for Node creation.
Here I think there might be something possible so that a \Drupal\file\Entity\File entity can be passed into the function, instead of the SplFileInfo entity that I have now.
More specifically, when I inspect what I am passing to the createDecisionNode(), here: $this->createDecisionNode($file_entity, $docx_file, $form_state);, I can see that the $docx_file =
SplFileInfo {#1336 ▼
  path: "/var/www/html/tmp/word_document_import/Files"
  filename: "file-sample_100kB.docx"
  basename: "file-sample_100kB.docx"
  pathname: "/var/www/html/tmp/word_document_import/Files/file-sample_100kB.docx"
  extension: "docx"
  realPath: "/var/www/html/tmp/word_document_import/Files/file-sample_100kB.docx"
  aTime: 2024-04-23 13:03:25
  mTime: 2024-04-23 12:17:02
  cTime: 2024-04-23 13:03:25
  inode: 8269895
  size: 111303
  perms: 0100644
  owner: 1000
  group: 1000
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
}

So, the current format that I am getting is not really a file that I can use as an attachment in my Node.
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    /* GET THE UPLOADED .ZIP */
    $file = $form_state->getValue('zip_file')[0];
    $file_entity = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($file);
    if (!$file_entity) {
      $form_state->setError($form['zip_file'], $this->t('Unable to load the uploaded zip file.'));
      return;
    }
  
    /* EXTRACT THE FILES FROM THE .ZIP */
    $file_path = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath($file_entity->getFileUri());
    $temp_dir = 'temporary://word_document_import';
    $temp_dir = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath($temp_dir);
    if (!file_exists($temp_dir)) {
      \Drupal::service('file_system')->mkdir($temp_dir, FileSystemInterface::CREATE_DIRECTORY | FileSystemInterface::MODIFY_PERMISSIONS);
      ksm("FILE DOES NOT EXIST");
    }
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if ($zip->open($file_path) === TRUE) {
      $zip->extractTo($temp_dir);
      $zip->close();
    } else {
      $form_state->setError($form['zip_file'], $this->t('Failed to extract the zip file.'));
      return;
    }
    $original_filename = $file_entity->getFilename();
    $zip_filename = pathinfo($original_filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $zip_filename = preg_replace('/_\d+$/', '', $zip_filename);
    $temp_dir_without_suffix = $temp_dir . '/' . $zip_filename; // the folder here with the extracted files
    if (!file_exists($temp_dir_without_suffix)) {
      $temp_dir_with_suffix = $temp_dir . '/' . $original_filename;
      if (file_exists($temp_dir_with_suffix) && is_dir($temp_dir_with_suffix)) {
        $temp_dir_without_suffix = $temp_dir_with_suffix;
      }
    }
    
    /* GET THE EXTRACTED FILES */
    $docx_files = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($temp_dir_without_suffix));

    /* CREATE NODES USING .DOCX FILES */
    foreach ($docx_files as $docx_file) {
      if ($docx_file->isFile() && $docx_file->getExtension() === 'docx') {
        $this->createDecisionNode($file_entity, $docx_file, $form_state);
      }
    }

    /* DELETE THE TEMORARY DIRECTORY */
    if (file_exists($temp_dir_without_suffix) && is_dir($temp_dir_without_suffix)) {
      $files = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($temp_dir_without_suffix, \RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
        \RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
      );
      foreach ($files as $file) {
        if ($file->isDir()){
          rmdir($file->getRealPath());
        } else {
          unlink($file->getRealPath());
        }
      }
      rmdir($temp_dir_without_suffix);
    }

    /* REDIRECT TO CONTENTS PAGE */
    $form_state->setRedirect('system.admin_content');
  }

Moving on to the createDecisionNode(), I am using the $file_entity, which was passed from before. The problem is that the $file_entity, is not the .docx file, but is the .zip file. So all the Nodes that are being created, instead of having the .docx that corresponds to their content, they get the .zip that was uploaded from the form.
  protected function createDecisionNode($file_entity, $docx_file, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $text_content = $this->readDocxFile($docx_file->getPathname());
    $filename = pathinfo($docx_file->getFilename(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($file_entity->id());

    $node = Node::create([
      'type' => 'decision',
      'title' => $filename,
      'field_attachment' => [
        'target_id' => $file->id(),
      ],
      'field_decision_text' => [
        'value' => $text_content,
        'format' => 'full_html',
      ],
    ]);

    $node->save();
  }

Now what I am basically trying to do, since I have all this information passed to my createDecisionNode():
SplFileInfo {#1336 ▼
  path: "/var/www/html/tmp/word_document_import/Files"
  filename: "file-sample_100kB.docx"
  basename: "file-sample_100kB.docx"
  pathname: "/var/www/html/tmp/word_document_import/Files/file-sample_100kB.docx"
  extension: "docx"
  realPath: "/var/www/html/tmp/word_document_import/Files/file-sample_100kB.docx"
  aTime: 2024-04-23 13:03:25
  mTime: 2024-04-23 12:17:02
  cTime: 2024-04-23 13:03:25
  inode: 8269895
  size: 111303
  perms: 0100644
  owner: 1000
  group: 1000
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
}

Isn't there a way, to use the path to the file, since I already have it, and take the File from there so that it can be passed in the Node field?
Or maybe there is a different better way to do this? Any help is appreciated.

You would have to move the docx files to some place where you dont delete them afterwards and create file entities of them

How do I create file entities from them?

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!file!src!Entity!File.php/class/File/9.0.x  you have a create and a save function

First you should save the .docx files on a permanent path before delete the temp folder.
After that you should use this saved file as parameter to your createDecisionNode method.
There is no need to pass the $file_entity to the creation method, because you should use the .docx file id as value to your field_attachment => target_id.
